# RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED No session available in the pool

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I am using the Spanner client library for Java and i configure the client using Spring.

After a while, the application start to log the following message but i don't understand why. The application concurrency is minimal. It's seem the sessions aren't reused. Any suggestions ?

> RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: No session available in the pool. Maximum number
>   of sessions in the pool can be overridden by invoking
>   SessionPoolOptions#Builder#setMaxSessions. Client can be made to block
>   rather than fail by setting
>   SessionPoolOptions#Builder#setBlockIfPoolExhausted.

```
@Configuration
public class SpannerConfig {

    @Value("${datasource.instanceId}")
    private String instance;

    @Value("${datasource.databaseId}")
    private String database;

    @Bean
    public Spanner spannerService() throws IOException {

        SessionPoolOptions sessionPoolOptions = SessionPoolOptions.newBuilder()
                .setFailIfPoolExhausted()
                .setMinSessions(5)
                .setMaxSessions(100)
                .build();

        SpannerOptions options = SpannerOptions.newBuilder()
                .setSessionPoolOption(sessionPoolOptions)
                .build();

        return options.getService();
    }


    @Bean
    public DatabaseClient spannerClient(Spanner spannerService) {
        DatabaseId databaseId = DatabaseId.of(spannerService.getOptions().getProjectId(), instance, database);
        return spannerService.getDatabaseClient(databaseId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a session leak. Make sure that you're using a try-with-resources expression around any DatabaseClient.singleUse* or DatabaseClient.ReadOnlyTransaction calls to ensure that the Transaction or ResultSet gets closed, allowing the corresponding session to be returned to the session pool.

Comment: while StackDriver tells otherwise ...the limit might either not be exceed - or not set.

Comment: `ResultSet rs = spannerClient.singleUse().executeQuery(statement);` is the only thing i do

Comment: Try putting this in a try-with-resources block:
try (ResultSet rs = spannerClient.singleUse().executeQuery(statement)) {
...
}

Answer (score 0):

you are setting `.setMaxSessions(100)` which obviously does exceed the predefined limit.

in principle, when one client already has allocated `100`, the next client can only allocate `0`.

the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sessions) for the sessions reads:

> **Note**: The Cloud Spanner client libraries manage sessions automatically.

... after reading into the source code, I'm sure that the error message is only thrown when using `.setFailIfPoolExhausted()`. that it reports an exhausted pool, might possibly be a bug, in case StackDriver monitoring tells the opposite.

Comment: If i remove the session SessionPoolOptions the result is the same but insted of RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED the client hang. I'll clarify that DatabaseClient is a singleton bean i reuse (only one client is created)

Comment: @lascarayf even if it's a singleton, it might take a while until those previously allocated sessions might be freed again. the instruction is just setting the limit, while the client might open too many new sessions and won't close the previous ones. see https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-spanner to get an idea, what is actually going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I will deal with eliminating the maximum limit. I tell you in a while what is happening. I am monitoring the sessions with stackdriver and i have less than 20 sessions.

Comment: @lascarayf the error message might possibly be a false positive - or might come from another setting, than it suggests. the client's code would be available here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/SessionPool.java opening an issue there, after debugging it, might be an option.

Comment: Yes Martin, the error RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED is because options.isFailIfPoolExhausted(). If i delete the line, the application hang until a session is released (never in my case)

Comment: @lascarayf either using the source-code version or stepping into it with Fernflower might be the best option. the basic example does not set any pool-options: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/spanner/snippets/DatabaseSelect.java ...neither a maximum nor a minimum.

Comment: Martin, i started using the client without the session options but the application began to hang. After that i put the session options but the problem continue. I open an issue https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/3786